# Codeblocks crashes while compiling

Tags: c++

When I try to compile a project, Codeblocks crashes.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,sum;
    ifstream in("sum.in");
    ofstream out("sum.out");
    in >> a >> b;
    sum = a + b;
    out << sum;
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: if codeblocks crashes while compiling then it should have nothing to do with the code you posted no?

Comment: it works when I try to compile other project, that's why I posted the code.

Comment: At first how it crashes while compiling ? You mean running program / exe. Second check without having sum.in. If it works fine then check content in sum.in. It would be always better to give proper description. Please do so. For me it work fine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If CodeBlocks indeed crashes for you, please post your operating system, CodeBlocks version number and a screenshot so that it is possible to research.

Comment: I have made a video that shows the problem : https://youtu.be/5NualZ2aqrs , maybe it will help